# What word describes someone who isn't exactly optimistic, but has a positive outlook?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need a word to describe someone who knows better than to expect the best, but can be happy in unfortunate circumstances.

I know phrases like "positive outlook" and "good disposition" could describe such a person, but I don't know any single words that would.

To differentiate between an optimist and the person I'm trying to describe:

When asking for a promotion, an optimist will expect to receive the promotion.
The other person will hope for a promotion, but won't be disappointed without it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it means to say this other person "hopes" for the promotion, rather than "expects" it. Surely unless he's pretty stupid (in which case he probably doesn't deserve and won't get the promotion) he should have an opinion on whether he's *likely* to get it or not. In short, I can't see where optimism and expectation fit in here. It seems all we're dealing with is a *pragmatist/realist* who's maybe not very aware of his own circumstances and likely future. [Happy-go-lucky](http://uk.imdb.com/title/tt1045670/) perhaps? (great film, that! :)

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

A person with a “positive outlook” could be described as a *positive* person. You could say he has a positive personality.

A positive person will hope to receive the promotion, but if he doesn’t he won’t be disappointed.

From dictionary.com:

> positive
>   9. emphasizing what is laudable, hopeful, or to the good; constructive: a positive attitude toward the future; positive things to say about a painting.
>   10. not speculative or theoretical; practical: a positive approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could describe a person who "can be happy in unfortunate circumstances" as *[sunny](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sunny)* -- cheerful.

Your example describes a person with a [glass-half-full](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glass-half-full) attitude. In the link to Wiktionary, the definition is given as "optimistic," but to me it is slightly less in that direction, and more someone who would make the best of whatever life sent their way. If you really want a single word, however, go with *sunny*.

Answer (score 3):

Will a realist do? 
A fatalist will succumb to faith, a pessimist will accept the worst, an optimist will always be disappointed, but a realist sounds just right. Doesn't he?

Comment: I think this correct - perhaps with an additional adjective - especially as the term realist is often taken as a synonym for 'pessimest'. A 'sunny realist' 'positive thinking realist'.

Answer (score 1):

The word that come to my mind immediately is "content" or "contented." Webster's New World Dictionary simply defines the word: "1.satisfied 2.willing; assenting"

Upon further reflection, I tend to think *optimism* and *idealism* are confused terms, especially by pessimists. I would say,

> When asking for a promotion, an *idealist* will expect to receive the promotion. *An optimist* will hope for a promotion, but won't be disappointed without it.

Because optimism is at the core of my being, this is how I would view the situation. Because the optimist is generally going to have an optimistic view, even of not getting the promotion. (Though I doubt many would realistically be "not disappointed" if they're *asking* for the promotion, even an optimist). But because there is this common misconception of *optimist*, I believe *content* or *contented* would suffice. Besides, *content* has such a pleasing ring to it, doesn't it?

Note: Webter's New World Dictionary defines as follows:

> idealism: 1. behavior or thought based on a conception of things as one thinks they should be  2. a striving for one's ideals
>
> optimism: 1.the belief that good ultimately prevails over evil  2. the tendency to take the most hopeful view of matters

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is sanguine?