# What do you call a person who is satisfied with what he has?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who is satisfied with what he has?
E.g. A person who is hopeful is called an optimist.

Comment: Not quite the same, but a related question: [What word describes someone who isn't exactly optimistic, but has a positive outlook?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93731)

Comment: I was going to say "complacent" but the dictionary definitions are all over the place on that one. Some just say to be happy with what one has, or of one's achievements. Then others include meanings such as with smugness, excessive satisfaction,  too confident, without awareness of some potential danger or defect or deficiency. Isn't your own word "satisfied" a good word?

Comment: @Yogesh - Chappo has correctly tagged this as a single-word-request. For those we need an example sentence, with a [blank] where the word you want would go. Primarily this enables us to understand whether you're looking for a noun or an adjective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That's only a duplicate if Yogesh wants an adjective.  The example of "optimist" suggests the correct answer would be a noun, though this isn't sufficiently clear. Hence this question should be closed as Off-topic for needing information on how it will be used (which is what I voted for; I have no idea why it says I've marked it as duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

I would say that person is *content.*

> content adjective [ after verb ] UK ​  /kənˈtent/ US ​  /kənˈtent/ ​
>   Pleased with your situation and not hoping for change or improvement:
>   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/content

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks like you've cited a dictionary definition, which we always applaud - *except, however, when the source isn't credited*. Could you please cite your source, ideally with a hyperlink? You can add this by using the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @AndyT - Well, *content* can also be a noun... (-:

Comment: @Chappo thanks for the feedback :) I've added the link.